# MySQL IF statement in a trigger- ELSE don't do anything

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to build a trigger in MySQL that will run after new rows are inserted into a table.
If there is an error detected, then I want to write that trigger to a table. Otherwise, I don't want to write the error to a table. I want to try and avoid adding endless blank rows.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER character_validation4 AFTER INSERT 
ON address FOR EACH ROW 
Begin 
IF(New.city REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]') 
THEN 
INSERT INTO errorlog (city, mainprocessid) Values("There is an error with the city", New.ID));
END
```

But I am seeing an error on the final bracket.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE 
TRIGGER character_validation4 AFTER INSERT 
ON address FOR EACH ROW 
Begin 
IF(New.city REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]') 
THEN 
INSERT INTO errorlog (city, mainprocessid) Values("There is an error with the city", New.ID);
END IF;
END \\

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I see "Unexpected End_of_Input expecting ';'" and "unexpected end" and "unexpected end"

Comment: I noticed the phpmyadmin tag, so I assume you're typing this into there. Add `DELIMITER //` to the beginning on the query (before `create`) and add `DELIMITER ;` at the end. Edit: also add `//` after the last `END`. See edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have an extra ")" right after New.ID . Try it this way

```
CREATE TRIGGER character_validation4 
AFTER INSERT ON address FOR EACH ROW Begin 
IF(New.city REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]') THEN INSERT INTO errorlog (city, mainprocessid) 
Values("There is an error with the city", New.ID);
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I see "Unexpected End_of_Input expecting ';'" and "unexpected end"

Comment: Add a END IF and put a ; after the end statement